# Disabling gutenbeg slow down post saving

Tags: block-editor

I have a clean latest WP installation.  php 7.2 mysql 5.7 LiteSpeed V7.1

When I add to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'use_block_editor_for_post', '__return_false' );
```

And press "save post" I get response from server after 2 minutes.
When I use gutenberg server response is around 3 sec.

Comment: What's the Network tab in dev tools showing you?

Comment: "request is not finished yet".